# Stop mousedown function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I've got a mousedown function. How can I stop the function when the mouse is released?

```
   $('#manRun').mousedown(function(e3) {
        var manID = get_id(this);
        e3.preventDefault();
        $(document).on('mousemove.moveMan', function(e2) {
           runing(e2, runBtn, manID);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another function for `mouseup` then unattach the handler.

```
$('#manRun').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off('mousemove.moveMan');
});
```

Comment: Looks good. Thanks. Shouldn't it be `.on('mouseup', function(e3) {`?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is`e` or `e3`, you can name it anything. This is just a variable for the "event". https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/